# Pass ENV variable with docker-compose.yml at runtime to Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to override the ENV values in my dockerfile depending on the environment (dev/uat/prod) from my docker-compose.yml.  Because some of the settings are sensitive I cant have these settings be apart of the build step of the docker image, instead these values must be overridden during runtime.  Ive been trying to deploy the following docker-compose via the docker stack deploy -c command, however i noticed my environment variables are not overriding the existing ones in the dockerfile.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
VOLUME /etc

ADD sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

ENV ENV_SETTINGS=ssldev
ENV ZK_HOST=zoo1
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms6048m -Xmx6048m -XX:+UseParNewGC - XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m - XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0 -XX:SurvivorRatio=1024 - XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=40 - XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=50 - XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:ConcGCThreads=8 - XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dspring.profiles.active=${ENV_SETTINGS}"

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail -k https://localhost:8080/status || exit 1
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
api:
    image: SOME_RANDOM_IMAGE
    ports:
        - "9083:8080"
    networks:
        - net
    deploy:
        restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
        mode: global
    environment:
        - ENV_SETTINGS: default,ssldev,postgres
        - ZK_HOST: zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181
networks:
nsp_net:
  external:
    name: net
```

Comment: The ENV statements in the Dockerfile are fully evaluated when the image is built.  If you `docker inspect` the image you should see _in the image_ `$JAVA_OPTS` ends with `-Dspring.profiles.active=ssldev`; changing `$ENV_SETTINGS` won't affect this now-fixed value.

Comment: How then can I override those values without rebuilding the image using the args option?  Since args can only be modified by requiring a rebuild how do other Docker images allow people to set the environment settings to override their configuration?

Comment: if the ENV statements are also fully evaluated during build whats the point in even having an environment option for docker-compose then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write an `ENV` statement in a Dockerfile, the `docker build` step fully expands that and "bakes in" the expanded value in the image it builds.  Docker does not provide a step that will re-expand environment variables at `docker run` time.  That is, your issue is not that `ENV_SETTINGS` is not getting set, but rather that `JAVA_OPTS` is not getting reinterpreted with the new value of `ENV_SETTINGS`.

To work around this, you can provide a shell script that sets up the environment.  I tend to structure images that need this in two parts:

1. The image's ENTRYPOINT is a script that sets up environment variables and does other preparation, and ends with `exec "$@"` to run the image's CMD or whatever command got passed to `docker run`.
2. The image's CMD is the actual command you want it to run.

Your shell script might look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=${ENV_SETTINGS:-ssldev}"
exec "$@"
```

The corresponding Dockerfile would look like:

```sh
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
# Don't declare VOLUME of anything, especially not system directories.
# Prefer COPY to ADD.
COPY sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
# Should be executable (chmod +x) as checked into source control.
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

ENV ENV_SETTINGS=ssldev
ENV ZK_HOST=zoo1
# Don't include -Dspring.profiles.active here.
# Do include -Djava.security.egd here.
# The JVM knows about $JAVA_OPTS.
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms6048m -Xmx6048m -XX:+UseParNewGC - XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m - XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0 -XX:SurvivorRatio=1024 - XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=40 - XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=50 - XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:ConcGCThreads=8 - XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
# Prefer quoted-word form.  But if you need a shell to process the
# command line, use unquoted form; don't explicitly "sh -c".
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail -k https://localhost:8080/status || exit 1
```

(I always prefer CMD to ENTRYPOINT: this wrapper pattern is useful and ubiquitous enough that it's better to have it available, and it's much easier to `docker run --rm -it imagename sh` to get an interactive debugging shell if you don't have to override the entrypoint to do it.  The exception is if I'm building a `FROM scratch` image where it's literally impossible to do anything other than run the bundled binary, but that's an exception.)

(Also note that newer JVMs, starting with a patch release of Java 8, have options to honor the container's memory limits, which leads to a much smaller `JAVA_OPTS` setting; see "Make JVM respect CPU and RAM limits" on [the openjdk image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/).)

Comment: thanks this helped me out quite a bit.  The only issue im seeing is that the entrypoint.sh is not updating the existing JAVA_OPTS env variable when i inspect the container after implementation.  It still seems to be only setting it via the ENV JAVA_OPTS statement, and not setting it from the entrypoint.sh

Comment: "JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xms6048m -Xmx6048m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0 -XX:SurvivorRatio=1024 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=40 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=50 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:ConcGCThreads=8 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.security.properties=/etc/disabled_tlsv1.properties"

Comment: My entrypoint #!/bin/sh
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dspring.profiles.active=${ENV_SETTINGS}"
exec "$@"

Comment: That is true; in the same way that if you have a shell, launch a background process that changes some environment variables, and `echo` the variable in the parent shell, the child can't change the parent's environment.  It is not a bug or a practical problem.  If you `docker run ... sh -c 'echo $JAVA_OPTS'` you'll see the right thing.