# docker react pass env variables during runtime

Tags: reactjs, docker, environment-variables

I have docker container with reactapp, I need to pass env variables during **runtime**(e.g. I invoke docker run) is there way to do it?
this question related to this one [Pass ENV variable with docker-compose.yml at runtime to Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974736/pass-env-variable-with-docker-compose-yml-at-runtime-to-dockerfile)

Comment: Yeah you can always do that, from the question you are referring to, if you pass env variables with `docker run -e foo=bar` command you can override the `foo` env variable in your dockerfile.

Comment: I'm no sure about react, react get all env variables and put it to build, so they become "frozen"(I just checked this), so, and after this I can't access runtime env variables from my react app

Comment: Did you try adding a step in `dockerfile` where it take the env variables and adds it to the `env.properties` files of your app... So during it's build it replaces those values in the file. Something like that's mentioned in this article https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/amp/